# Rails - add an array of another class on a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, forms

I apologise if the question is quite simple, I'm fairly new to Rails. I'm building a meal planner application, and am trying to have it so that a user can create a meal, and add items to that meal. E.g. a meal of 'fish & chips' would include the items 'fish' and 'chips'. As I understand it, I think I need a way of creating an array of items on the meal creation form - but how do I do that?

Relevant parts of meal.rb:

```
has_many :items
accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
```

and item.rb

```
belongs_to :meal
```

What do I need to add to the meal form partial for it to accept an array of items? I apologise, I have no idea where to start! Alternatively, if there is a simpler way of doing it, please let me know. But I don't want to have a list of 'item_1_id', 'item_2_id' etc on the meal!! Thanks!!

```
<%= form_for(@meal) do |f| %>
  <% if @meal.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@meal.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this meal from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @meal.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :category %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :child_id %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :child_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :time %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :time %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: First thing I figured from our case scenario that you need to have `many to many` relationship instead of `one to many`. `An item may belong to more than one meal.` And about adding the related items to a meal you can use https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form gem. Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: Yes, I think you did, thanks for the suggestion, will look into it!

Answer (score 0):

There is a great railscast episode that covers this. Also, you would want to use javascript to have a "add item" link. This example below, will always have one new item available.

You would want to do something like this

view

```
<%= f.fields_for :items do |builder| %>
  <fieldset>

  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

controller

```
@meal.items.build
```

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for that, will look into those, looks like just what I'm after.